# Optimizing solution of Sum of Pairs: Codewars in Python

Tags: performance, python-3.x, memoization

[image]I need help to optimize my code for huge lists with approx. 10000000 elements. Is there a way to improve my algorithm or should I try to build a new one using a completely different approach?
Task: given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that add up to form the sum.

```py
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    lst1 = []
    for n in ints:
        if n in lst1:
            return [s-n, n]
        lst1.append(s-n)

lst3 = list(range(1,10000000))

sum_pairs(lst3, 20000000)

*Times out :(

#Using set() every time we add new item to the list doesn't help

def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    lst1 = []
    for n in ints:
        lst2 = set(lst1)
        if n in lst2:
            return[s-n, n]
        lst1.append(s-n)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the code?

Comment: Btw you should tag this as python

Comment: I mean that you should just completely take the lst1 list out of the program and use a set instead.

Comment: Please replace the top image with a code block containing equivalent text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a set as lst1 instead of a list. Every time you check if n is in lst1, it’s \$ O(n) \$ time complexity. Using a set instead will lower that to \$ O(1) \$.

Comment: Correct answer in last example is [3, 7], not [5, 5]  because 7 appears in the list of integers before second "5"

Comment: You’re right, somehow I misread it. Nvm, all you need is to use a set instead of a list. Then it should work.

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about sets as  distinct data types, remembered only function call, nevermind that   :)